# Структура базы данных Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. У меня есть база данных Oracle. Использую Oracle 11g express edition. Нужно вытащить структуры базы данных. Но как сделать это через apex которым я пользуюсь не знаю. По сути я просто захожу через веб интерфейс. Подскажите пожалуйста как оттуда можно выгрузить структуру. Если нужны скрины моего apex'а. Напишите могу приложить, что бы удобней было скоординировать меня. Спасибо заранее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите конечную цель. Не улавливаю взаимосвязи между  apex и структурой данных.

Comment: @0xdb ну у меня в apex есть 5 таблиц. Вот мне нужно в выходных данных с работой сдать структуру базы данных + er диаграмму. Например в ibexpert была такая функция как поглядеть структуру базы данных Ну все таблицы со связями и полями грубо говоря. Вот и тут мне это нужно как выходные данные. ER диаграмма на сколько я помню делается на сторонних программах, а как мне достать структуру моей базы? Надеюсь объяснил понятно. Если что спрашивайте.

Comment: Немного прояснилось. А в каком виде Вы желаете получить структуру БД?  Привидите короткий и наглядный пример ожидаемого резултата.

Comment: @0xdb ну то же самое что и ER диаграмма я думаю. Только с оракловской стороны а не со сторонних программ типо StarUML на котором я сделал ER диаграмму. Могу привести её в вопросе как пример.

Comment: @0xdb что то типо этого)

Comment: Т.е. нужно сгенерировать ER-диаграму из существующих в схеме apex.xyz таблиц?

Comment: @0xdb да. Вы всё правильно поняли. И желательно как можно быстрей. Просто сегодня уже сдавать работу)

Comment: Ну возмите Sql-developer, там есть кнопка - модель.

Comment: @0xdb а можно по конкретней? Я просто не знаю что это и не разу не пользовался. Это что то в веб интерфейсе apex'а?

Comment: Про apex я ничего не могу сказать. Попробуйте с [SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).